# Maven Webservice Plugin working with install, not deploy

Tags: java, deployment, maven-2, web-services

I have a maven module that uses the plugin `jaxws-maven-plugin`. I have the webservice up and running and when browsing to the `.../myWebservice?wsdl`, I get the WSDL. No problem.

This also works when running the `wsimport` maven goal through:

`<plugin>

  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  <executions>

    <execution>

      <goals>

        <goal>wsimport</goal>

      </goals>

    </execution>

  </executions>

  <configuration>

    <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>

      <wsdlUrls>

        <wsdlUrl>http://host/f/soap/fWeb?wsdl</wsdlUrl>

      </wsdlUrls>

  </configuration>

</plugin>`

When running

`mvn clean install`

All is fine... However, it doesn't work when I run

`mvn clean deploy`

Looking at the logged out parameters, they are identical in both cases:

`[INFO] jaxws:wsimport args: [-s, D:\works2\f-service\src\main\java, -d, D:\works2\f-
service\target\classes, -Xnocompile, http://host/f/soap/fWeb?wsdl]
parsing WSDL...`

After a really long timeout, that feels like a http timeout, it fails with this message:

`[ERROR] Unexpected end of file from server
Failed to read the WSDL document: http://host/f/soap/fWeb?wsdl, because

1) could not find the document;

2) the document could not be read;

3) the root element of the document is not wsdl:definitions.

ERROR failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):
At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.
Failed to parse the WSDL.`

It's a bit confusing, since it takes so long... In fact the full namespace is not mentioned in the WSDL, root element is `<definitions>`, not `<wsdl:definitions>`, but then why does it work with `mvn clean install`...?

Thanks!
Raoul

Comment: What error do you get when running clean deploy? Can you add the relevant part of your `pom.xml` and of the trace to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have no idea why `mvn clean install` and `mvn clean deploy` don't have a consistent result. First, `wsimport` is bound to the `generate-sources` phase and is executed in both case much earlier. Second, the `deploy` phase which occurs right after `install` doesn't do much more things, as documented:

> done in an integration or release environment, copies the final package to the remote repository for sharing with other developers and projects.

So, really, I don't see how copying an artifact to a repository can impact `wsimport` or make the build fail on something related to the WSDL. Very, very weird. Maybe run `mvn -X clean deploy` to see if you can get more information.

Anyway, I have a few suggestions about the jaxws-maven-plugin configuration.

The first one would be to **not** generate sources in `src/main/java`. IMO, generated sources should go under the `target` directory as you want to be able to delete them during a `clean`. So I'd suggest to use the default value which is `${project.build.directory}/jaxws/wsimport/java` or something like `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws` instead (this is the standard maven pattern for generated stuff). But this is a side note, this won't solve your issue :)

The second suggestion is about the `<wsdlUrls>` configuration. Instead of using `<wsdlUrls>`, why don't you get the WSDL (as a file) and put it in `src/wsdl` (or another location in which case you'll have to specify it using the `<wsdlLocation>` element). This should help to workaround the timeout issue.